# How can I get rid of apostrophe?

Tags: python

I am passing in a textfile and I wish to get rid of all possible aprostrophe.
I am using the following function:

```
def apost(nostop):
    for n in nostop:
        final=[]
        removed=[]
        for y in n:
            r=remove_apos(y)
            final.append(r)
        removed.append(final)
    print("Task 2: Apostrophy removed!")
    return removed
```

And this the body of remove_apos:

```
def remove_apos(stemmed):
    for suffix in ["'s", "'v", "'t", "'d", "'r", "'"]:
        if stemmed.endswith(suffix):
            return stemmed[:-len(suffix)]
    return stemmed
```

When I pass in a sentence: `football's awesome`
It is returning me `football'`
I am unable to get rid of the apostrophe.
Moreover, when I print `removed`, I get: `[[u'football\u2019s']]`

Comment: This question is more suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @PeterGibson, No, it's not as it does not work as intended. Please read a [Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @holroy Interesting thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your problem appears to be that you are comparing against an ASCII apostrophe, but your text contains, or also contains, Unicode apostrophes.

The plain old apostrophe, U+0027, is what you get by default when you hit the ['/"] key on a US keyboard without hitting shift.

The "RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK", U+2019, is something else entirely. You might get that from a word processor, or email program that tries to automatically convert from straight quotes to angled quotes. (Word, and Office Email, both do this in text boxes, for example. As does Libre Office in a document.)

You should probably use a regex to match all these possible characters.

Comment: I am trying this:
with codecs.open(sys.argv[1], 'r', 'utf8') as fil:
    for line in fil:
        z=re.sub("'","",line)
        dataset.append(z.lower().strip().split())

But this too doesn't seem to work. I have to open it in 'utf-8' otherwise stemming and lemmatization don't work

Comment: You have the right idea, but need to put both regular apostrophe and U+2019 into a character match. Or just replace the U+2019 with ' and proceed from there. `re.sub("[\u2019'](?:[rv]e|[dst]|)\b", "", line)` - should handle "Smiths'" (possessive plural), "I've", "you're", "he's", "we'd", and "don't".

Answer (score 1):

It's really easy to remove all apostrophes:

```
def remove_apos(nostop):
    return "".join(char for char in nostop if char != "'")
```

You could also remove them with a `while` loop and the `str.remove()` method:

```
def remove_apos(nostop):
    while "'" in nostop:
        nostop = nostop.remove("'")
    return nostop
```

Comment: I still receive football'

def apost(nostop):
    m=[]
    for x in nostop:
        while "'" in x:
            x.remove("'")
        m.append(x)
    print(m)
    return m

Comment: @minks: You aren't running the code that I gave.  You are still using a list.

Comment: It still doesn't work if I don't use the list. I think it is the encoding error.